# Unable to Execute a (DELETE) Query on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, delete-row, sql-delete

I want to delete all the rows in the data base that contain the URL in which .jpg extension comes!

I am using

```
 try{
 java.sql.Statement mystat=connection.createStatement();
 String delete_jpg="DELETE FROM mytable WHERE mycol LIKE '%.jpg%' ";
 mystat.executeUpdate(delete_jpg);
 }catch(Exception e){
  }
```

Executing this query using Java JDBC gives no errors at all but it is not deleting the rows as well! Please can somebody tell me that what I'm doing wrong please!!!

Example URLs are:

```
 images/affiliation-logo4.png HTTP/1.1
 images/661.jpg HTTP/1.1
 footerslider/images/blue-left-arrow.png HTTP/1.1
 footerslider/images/blue-right-arrow.png HTTP/1.1
 media/contentHeader/32.jpg HTTP/1.1     //I want to delete this type of rows
 index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=543 HTTP/1.1
 images/favic.ico HTTP/1.1
 src/ HTTP/1.0
 uiit/faculty.php?dept_id=31 HTTP/1.1
 uims/faculty.php?dept_id=32 HTTP/1.1
 media/profile/dhS1t8X.jpg HTTP/1.1     //I want to delete this type of rows
 media/profile/SSbkpgG.jpg HTTP/1.1     //I want to delete this type of rows
```

Comment: Is the transaction possibly rolled back? Show us how you execute the query.

Comment: Are you committing after deleting?

Comment: Show us the Java code

Comment: How do you know the are no errors? You appear to be swallowing the exception. put e.printStackTrace() in the catch block and re-run it, then post the exception if there is one

Comment: i am using the block of catch in the code and here i forget to add the catch statements sorry for that but not exception has been thrown by the code !
 I have checked my data base no changes occur in it

Comment: Also, executeUpdate returns the number of rows it deletes - try this : int rowCount = mystat.executeUpdate(delete_jpg);System.out.println("Deleted : " + rowCount ); This won't fix anything, just help the diagnosis.

Comment: IT GIVES DELETED: 0 @DaveHows

Comment: To me, that indicates that either a) your statement is wrong or b) you are running this statement against one database, but checking against another. If you were to change this to a select statement, how many rows would it retrieve?

Comment: Good suggestion wait let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from your sample URLs I see that the pattern is:

```
 media/profile/dhS1t8X.jpg HTTP/1.1     //I want to delete this type of rows
```

The thing is that you're doing correctly but the pattern should be like:

```
try{
 java.sql.Statement mystat=connection.createStatement();
 String delete_jpg="DELETE FROM mytable WHERE mycol LIKE '%.jpg %' ";  //HERE YOU HAVE TO ADD A WHITE SPACE AFTER THE .jpg as you can also seen in your sample URL!
 mystat.executeUpdate(delete_jpg);
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Do it and will definitely help you!

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm thanks and now it works for me for the whole Data base and other queries also thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try this modification to your statement:

`String delete_jpg="DELETE FROM mytable WHERE mycol LIKE '%' + .jpg + '%' ";`

Comment: SEVERE: null
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier ".jpg" could not be bound.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
........................